# Why is tar extraction too slow in zfs?

Tags: zfs, lxd

I am using an `lxd` container, and trying to copy a `hadoop` installation tarball, into the container from the host.

Initially, the container was using ZFS as a file system. The next step that I did was to extract the tarball. That took a **lot** of time. Normal extraction merely takes approximately 5-7 seconds on my laptop, whereas inside the container, the process was so slow that I had to interrupt it manually.

Suspecting that ZFS might be the problem, I created a new container, with `dir` as the filesystem, and *voila*, the extraction was done in 5 seconds!

What is the problem between ZFS and `tar`?

---

Meanwhile, I've read that ZFS becomes slow when reaching it's quota [here](https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/the-container-r-w-is-very-slower-than-host/1432/12).

> Specifically, they say:
>
> ```
> Poor write performance very close to the quota is a design choice made in
>
> OpenZFS 7793 - ztest fails assertion in dmu_tx_willuse_space (3ec3bc2).
> ```

I'd specified a size of 4 GB, and am sure that the current size didn't even reach 500 MB. So, that shouldn't be a problem, in my opinion.

Comment: How was the pool configured? (Is it configured to use a whole disk, or only a file or something? Is the data in the pool replicated, compressed, deduped, etc.?) How is the 4GB limit you set enforced? (At logical ZFS level, physical level, or something else?)

Comment: I'll post the `lxd init` configuration, in a while. Would that be enough?

Comment: It would probably be better to supply the output of “zpool status” and “zfs get all <your-pool/path/to/your-container-fs>”, since you think the problem is with the filesystem.